# Unable to create a resized image using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS Lambda function to resize any image that is put in my s3 bucket. I have created an event for every Object creation in s3 bucket for the Lambda function to trigger. My Handler code for Lambda is as follows:

```
var async = require('async'),
    gm = require('gm').subClass({
    imageMagick: true
}) // Enable ImageMagick integration.
, request = require('request').defaults({
    encoding: null
});

var knox = require('knox');
var client = knox.createClient({
key: 'myKey',
secret: 'mySecretKey',
bucket: 'MyBucketName'
});


//hardcoded Value to get the Image url
var s3value = '.s3.amazonaws.com/';
var https = 'https://'

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
var imageUrl = https + srcBucket + s3value + srcKey //My Http Url for image stored in s3 bucket.
request(imageUrl, function (err, res, res1) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        gm(res1).resize(120)
            .toBuffer('jpg', function (err, buffer) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var ImageName = "/" + imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.indexOf(".")) + "-1x" + imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.indexOf("."), imageUrl.length); //Renaming the present image
                    client.putBuffer(buffer, ImageName, function (err, response1) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(response1.socket._httpMessage.url);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
});
context.done();
}
```

My Problem is that when I store an image in S3 the resized image is not getting created in my s3 Bucket. I am unable to understand why I am unable to create a resized image in the same s3 bucket. Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Is your Lambda function actually being invoked? You should add some logging to your index.js (use console.log), then upload an S3 object, and then take a look at the CloudWatch logs for your Lambda function.

Comment: My lambda function is getting invoked. I also added console.log statements to verify it on cloudwatch. My observation  is that request npm node module is not getting called for the given n url.

Comment: I would use the S3 getObject API call to retrieve the object rather than an HTTP request. One of the sample Lambda event functions does exactly this (see the s3-get-object blueprint).

Comment: if you added console.log messages, please share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `context.done()` outside the callback function for `request()`.  This will end the Lambda function before any image resizing completes.  You should only call `context.done()` when all processing has completed or failed.

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var srcKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var imageUrl = https + srcBucket + s3value + srcKey //My Http Url for image stored in s3 bucket.
    request(imageUrl, function (err, res, res1) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail(err);
        } else {
            gm(res1).resize(120)
                .toBuffer('jpg', function (err, buffer) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        context.fail(err);
                    } else {
                        var ImageName = "/" + imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.indexOf(".")) + "-1x" + imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.indexOf("."), imageUrl.length); //Renaming the present image
                        client.putBuffer(buffer, ImageName, function (err, response1) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                context.fail(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log(response1.socket._httpMessage.url);
                                context.succeed("It worked");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
    // Don't call context.done() here, the callback hasn't run yet
    //context.done();
}
```